# inequality proof $a^n - 1 > n(a^\frac{n+1}{2} - a^\frac{n-1}{2})$

Tags: inequality

Prove that if $a > 1$, then $a^n - 1 > n(a^\frac{n+1}{2} - a^\frac{n-1}{2})$.
$$\\$$
The problem doesn't specify what is $n$, but I assume it is a natural number (I tried with 1,2,.. and it works). The problem is also in a AM-GM material, but I don't see how can I use it. I tried some factorizations, but I didn't see something useful and I don't have much ideas about what can I make.

Comment: There is typo in right side of inequality

Comment: oh thank you, now its right

Comment: It's wrong. Try $a=2$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}.$ By the way it's true for any reals $a>1$ and $n\geq1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
a^n-1 &\ge n(a^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}) = na^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(a-1)&&\iff\\
a^{n-1}+\dots+a+1 = \frac{a^n-1}{a-1} &\ge na^{\frac{n-1}{2}} &&\iff\\
\frac{a^{n-1}+\dots+a+1}{n}&\ge a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}
\end{aligned}$$
which is true by $AM\ge GM$.

Comment: nice, the strict inequality holds because the $a_i$'s are different.

Comment: @RickSanchez only for $n\neq 1$.

Comment: Equivalently, a more direct approach is to apply AM-GM to the telescoping series (we want to sum $n$ terms to get the LHS): $ \sum ( a^{i+1} - a^i ) \geq n (a-1)a^{(n-1)/2}$.